# Enable/Disable the swipe to delete functionality on UITableViewCell dynamically

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6

I have added a gesture recognizer on the UITableViewCell to drag the cell to other view within the same view controller. For this I have added a long press gesture recognizer to the cell.

But I also need swipe to delete functionality when we are not dragging the cell. But when I start the drag and move in one direction(right or left) then the Cell fires the call for swipe-to-delete(which is default) as well.

I need to stop this call at this moment.Reloading the tableView is not an option as After reloading I would loose the selected cell for dragging.

Comment: Tried it....But this function is called everytime table is reloaded.... and as already stated I cant reload the table.And moreover the editingstyle property is a readonly property for the cell......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few guesses if any of them works for you-

1. Check the `tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method.
2. Turn off the editing mode put swipe gesture and long press gesture directly along with the function to handle multiple gestures(just to be precise).

Now, what you can do here is that increase the long press time or just add the function to detect multiple gestures.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{ 
    return YES; 
}
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to put a custom swipe-to-delete gesture?

Comment: Now, what you can do here is that increase the long press time or just add the function to detect multiple gestures.                  `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}`

Comment: @anky_beliveMe ---  Thanks Man ... it worked fine.....  Just had to {return No;} in order to achieve my functionality

Comment: just edit the answer to this function you specified in the comment . would be happy to do so then....

Comment: Done. I made the changes.!!

Answer (score 2):

Try below code its one of the UITableViewDelegate methods available in ios

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView  editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Detemine if it's in editing mode
if (self.editing)
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete; //enable when editing mode is on
}

return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

You can also turn off swipe to delete for specific rows in specific section using **indexPath** which is available in this method

**Swift 3 Version:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    if tableView.isEditing {
        return .delete
    }
    return .none
}
```